# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: string, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to add the option for the quantity to be adjusted but I get an error saying "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget"
How do I provide this, to this code? [image: img]

```
 trailing: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), onTap: () {}),
            new Text(cart_prod_qty),
            new GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down), onTap: () {})
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: It sounds like `cart_prod_qty` is `null`

Comment: Try to interpolate it: Text('$cart_prod_qty'),

Comment: @FellipeMalta Not a good ideia. It won't fail on run but the text is going to show "null", instead.

Comment: I thought the variable has already been declared, was just a thought @HugoPassos

Comment: It showed null. The cart_prod_qty has been declared as 1. But also the first error came back https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSIH4.png

Comment: Where is `cart_prod_qty` defined? Clearly that is `null` and not `1` as you expect, but you don't show it anywhere. You need to provide more code.

Comment: Here https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSQg0.png and the rest of the code is here  i.stack.imgur.com/m180K.png i.stack.imgur.com/bbCsp.png i.stack.imgur.com/v4iQ0.png

Comment: Please don't use images for posting code. Extract the main part and put it in the question. If it's absolutely need to send big part of code, consider posting it on [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and sending link here

Comment: You need to edit your question and actually copy and paste the code **as text** into it. Also, your error is a simple typo.

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Comment: No I haven't been able to fix it :(

Answer (score 43):

You should check null safe

```
Text(cart_prod_qty??'default value'),
```

Comment: And I'd like to add: In flutter, it often makes sense to *not* create a `Text` widget in this case, e.g. in all kinds of `Tiles` and other stuff: 
`Tile(..., subtitle: cart_prod_qty == null ? null : Text(cart_prod_qty)),`
This will render more nicely because it has no empty `Text` widget around.

Comment: Helped me understand my dumb mistake.

Comment: best answer.....

Answer (score 9):

Just check for null and give a default

```
Text(cart_prod_qty!=null?cart_prod_qty:'default value'),
```

You can keep it empty if you wish

```
Text(cart_prod_qty!=null?cart_prod_qty:''),
```

Or else you can make text widget optional

```
cart_prod_qty!=null? Text(cart_prod_qty): Container()
```

Answer (score 5):

The error itself shows what's wrong in the code, Text widget works only with string and for null they intentionally have thrown an exception. 
Check text.dart file implementation where they added throwing an exception.

```
assert(
         data != null,
         'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
       ),
```

To solve above error you have to provide some default text.

```
new Text(cart_prod_qty!=null?cart_prod_qty:'Default Value'),
```

Answer (score 4):

An advice for you in this case and all who are reading this.

When you add an non direct String value to the Text() don't directly insert it like you did in this example:

```
Text(cart_prod_qty)
```

Because you can get "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget" like I did.

So I advise you to practice this in the future it's more safe:

```
Text('${cart_prod_qty}')
```

Comment: Thank you alot, you save my soul, really informative 

Answer (score 4):

if you know for certain that it's not null, then you can safely do this:

```
Text(cart_prod_qty!),
```

to me, when it's definitely not null in the usage case, it's cleaner than doing this:

```
Text(cart_prod_qty ?? ''),
```

Answer (score 3):

The value may be empty therefore youre getting a null error try this if its an optional field:

```
new Text(cart_prod_qty == null ? '' : cart_prod_qty),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that your string is nullable you could do something like this. Although I used the visibility widget because I don't want my widget to be displayed if it's null.

```
class NullableTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final String? text;
      final TextStyle? textStyle;
      const NullableTextWidget({Key? key, this.text,this.textStyle}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Visibility(
          visible: text != null,
          child: Text(
            text ?? "",
            style: textStyle,),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just set Text widget value optional like

```
Text(value ?? ""),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is visible. You're passing null to Text widget. `new Text(cart_prod_qty)` This can be due to delay of response from api (if you're using it). Or there is no value in the variable "cart_prod_qty". You can handle it like this: `new Text(cart_prod_qty != null ? cart_prod_qty.toString : '')`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while fetching data from Firebase . It was initially: **Text(widget.title)**  - it caused the error .

Later, I transformed the Text() into this format:
**Text('${widget.title}')**

- this interpolates the fetched data inside the Text() widget .

If you receive a null value return , that would be a server issue .

Hope this might help someone .

Answer (score -1):

> I have faced that same problem.... I have resolved it by using   a
> **"new"** keyword before Text...

child: new Text(mydata[1]["2"][k]),

Comment: Could you exaplain more details with your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I GOT SAME ERROR DUE TO THIS

**BEFORE**:

```
title:  Text(widget.title)
```

**AFTER:**

```
title:  Text('ram')
```

**THIS SOLVED MY ERROR**

To solve this error Add **Double quote or single quote** `title:  Text('ram')`