# Null value inside the Text widget that returns from an API

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-text

I have an API call that returns a null value and I want to handle it in the `Text` widget, if the value is null, return and empty string like this `''` or and empty Text widget like this `Text('')`, if the text is not null, return the widget as it is.

```
 Text('FLIGHT ${data.locations.pickup.flightInfo.flightNumber}' ?? ''),
```

I just check it inside the Text widget like in the code above, is this not the correct approach? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68690423/13997210)

Answer (score 1):

this is what you can do

`Text(${data.locations.pickup.flightInfo.flightNumber} == null ? '' : 'FLIGHT ${data.locations.pickup.flightInfo.flightNumber}'),`

though it seems long but it works or you can use null safety to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the null safety check like this :

```
Text(data.locations.pickup.flightInfo.flightNumber != null  ? 'FLIGHT ${data.locations.pickup.flightInfo.flightNumber}' : ""),
```